# Is there choreography to the Dance of Joy?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

During Angel and crew's visit to Pylea, Lorne's mother instructs [Numfar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycFqzNxiTwY) to do the Dance of Joy. Has there ever been an official or at least widely accepted full choreography for this dance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numfar (or Namphar) was secretly portrayed by Angel series creator Joss Whedon.
[According to Andy Hallett](https://www.tve.co.il/story/1888) the dance wasn't included in the shooting script which would suggest that it was largely improvised.

> **Q.** *Dance of Joy? How could you keep a straight face during the shoot - in other words, how many takes did it take?*
>
> **A.** *A lot! But I didn’t know it was him. He was keeping it a secret...And then I saw Namphar and he did his dance and I thought "Oh my god! Who IS this guy?" I thought he was trash. And... how did I find out? He yelled "Cut!"*

Comment: I suspect this is as good an answer as I will get on this topic.

Comment: RIP Andy Hallett :(